# Simplifying modulus expressions and an unknown expression? discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, modular-arithmetic, computer-science, regular-expressions

I have a few questions below that I need help with
a) I don't really understand what that symbol means and how to solve it
b) How do u simplify this without a calculator
c) I got 2^-r = 0, iss this true?

[image]

Comment: $\Pi_{k=2}^n a_k$ is the product of all factors $a_k$ from $k=2$ to $n$.

Comment: so how do u continue on with part A. If k =2, we have 1-1/4 = 3/4. so 3/4 is a factor, and the other is (1-1/n^2). is the answer 3/4*(1-1/n^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a):

1) $\prod_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k+1}{k}=\frac{3}{2}.\frac{4}{3}...\frac{n}{n-1}.\frac{n+1}{n}=\frac{n+1}{2}$

2) $\prod_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k-1}{k}=\frac{1}{2}.\frac{2}{3}...\frac{n-2}{n-1}.\frac{n-1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}$

$\prod_{k=2}^{n}(1-\frac{1}{k^2})= \prod_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k^2-1}{k^2}=\prod_{k=2}^{n}(\frac{k+1}{k})(\frac{k-1}{k})=\frac{n+1}{2n}$ (using the result from 1 and 2)

Part (b), see lab's answer.

Part(c):
Recall the sum of geometric series: $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}a^r=\frac{a-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$$
So, $$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^r=\frac{\frac{1}{2}-(\frac{1}{2})^\infty}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}-0}{\frac{1}{2}}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$3^3=27\equiv-1\pmod7\implies3^{1000}=3(3^3)^{333}\equiv3(-1)^{333}\equiv-3\equiv4$$

or $$3^6\equiv(-1)^2\pmod7\equiv1,1000\equiv4\pmod6\implies3^{1000}\equiv3^4\pmod7$$

Comment: thanks, its a little hard to figure out $$-3\equiv4$$ comes to be

Comment: @user124627, $$-a=m-a\pmod m$$